# how can i display multiple graphs on a single page in zend framework?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-studio, zeta-components

I'm generating linear graphs in ZEND framework using ez components, I would like to display some of em on a single page as a dashboard, how should I do that?

i'm thinking about creating an action for every graph in the controller but I couldn't find the proper way to display them as a dashboard

Answer (score 0):

In typical MVC scenario single action renders single page so it is probably better idea to create model class for rendering the graphs and call it from action controller to populate view variables

Comment: Can you please provide me with an example of this, i m new to zend framework, i got the idea but i have dont see how to implement it. & Thank you for your reply